# Converting a Spark Dataframe to a Scala Map collection

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to find the best solution to convert an entire Spark dataframe to a scala Map collection. It is best illustrated as follows:

To go from this (in the Spark examples):

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

df.show
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

To a Scala collection (Map of Maps) represented like this:

```
val people = Map(
Map("age" -> null, "name" -> "Michael"),
Map("age" -> 30, "name" -> "Andy"),
Map("age" -> 19, "name" -> "Justin")
)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think your question makes sense -- your outermost `Map`, I only see you are trying to stuff values into it -- you need to have key / value pairs in your outermost `Map`. That being said:

```
val peopleArray = df.collect.map(r => Map(df.columns.zip(r.toSeq):_*))
```

Will give you:

```
Array(
  Map("age" -> null, "name" -> "Michael"),
  Map("age" -> 30, "name" -> "Andy"),
  Map("age" -> 19, "name" -> "Justin")
)
```

At that point you could do:

```
val people = Map(peopleArray.map(p => (p.getOrElse("name", null), p)):_*)
```

Which would give you:

```
Map(
  ("Michael" -> Map("age" -> null, "name" -> "Michael")),
  ("Andy" -> Map("age" -> 30, "name" -> "Andy")),
  ("Justin" -> Map("age" -> 19, "name" -> "Justin"))
)
```

I'm guessing this is really more what you want. If you wanted to key them on an arbitrary `Long` index, you can do:

```
val indexedPeople = Map(peopleArray.zipWithIndex.map(r => (r._2, r._1)):_*)
```

Which gives you:

```
Map(
  (0 -> Map("age" -> null, "name" -> "Michael")),
  (1 -> Map("age" -> 30, "name" -> "Andy")),
  (2 -> Map("age" -> 19, "name" -> "Justin"))
)
```

Comment: That worked. I actually misspoke. I only needed a collection of Maps and the first line gave me exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First get the schema from Dataframe

```
val schemaList = dataframe.schema.map(_.name).zipWithIndex//get schema list from dataframe
```

Get the rdd from dataframe and mapping with it

```
dataframe.rdd.map(row =>
  //here rec._1 is column name and rce._2 index
  schemaList.map(rec => (rec._1, row(rec._2))).toMap
 ).collect.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val map =df.collect.map(a=>(a(0)->a(1))).toMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
```

if the result is needed in a map instead of array(map)